# Передача в метод нескольких параметров и возвращение измененных параметров обратно

Tags: java

Есть класс c переменными

```
class sr
{
 private int value1, value2;
}
```

Но это лишь пример, поэтому класс такой скудный
Есть функция, в которую передается одна из переменных класса. Выгляди всё примерно так:

```
void method(int value, byte x)
{
     switch(value)
      {
        case 9: x--; value++; break;
        case 10: x-=2; value++; break;
        case 11: x-=3; value++; break;
        case 12: x-=4; value++; break;
        case 13: x-=5; value++; break;
        case 14: x-=7; value++; break;
        case 15: x-=9; value++; break;
      }
}
```

Вот как вызывается этот метод:

```
if(true)
  method(sr.value1, counter);
else
  method(sr.value2, counter);
```

Мне нужно, чтобы переменная класса менялась, когда "попадала" в функцию.
Ибо когда делаю вывод, показывает, что ничего не меняется
Как это сделать?

Comment: немного не понятно, можете что за класс и что менять более подробнее объяснить?

Comment: В метод передаётся значение переменной, а не она сама. Таким образом переменную класса поменять невозможно.

Comment: @banme как тогда можно сделать?

Comment: Не понятно где вызывается метод. Если в другом методе того же класса, то в ответе ниже написать так `sr.value1 = method(sr.value1, counter)` вместо `counter = ...` Если в другом месте, то надо ещё что-то решать с `private`

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно для вашего случая - решение в лоб. С одним из параметров работаете "напрямую", как с полем класса, а не передаете его в метод параметром (но это костыль кривой):

```
int method(int value)
{
     switch(value)
      {
        case 9: counter--; value++; break;
        case 10: counter-=2; value++; break;
        case 11: counter-=3; value++; break;
        case 12: counter-=4; value++; break;
        case 13: counter-=5; value++; break;
        case 14: counter-=7; value++; break;
        case 15: counter-=9; value++; break;
      }
 return value;
}
```

вызов:

```
if(true)
  sr.value1 = method(sr.value1);
else
  sr.value2 = method(sr.value2);
```

По хорошему, для данных не одного типа, нужно создать объект-модель (для нескольких однотипных данных достаточно массива), которая будет хранить в себе необходимые значения, передавать ее параметром, в методе устанавливать новые значения и возвращать ее в качестве результата, затем извлекать из нее данные.

Comment: Мне нужно изменять не только counter, но и переменную класса, которая передается в метод

Answer (score 1):

В Java используется передача по значению. То есть примитивные типы, переданные в метод, копируются, а для объектов грубо говоря создается еще одна ссылка.

То есть если у вас есть переменная int a = 1 и вы передали ее в метод, то JVM грубо говоря создаст переменную $a и скопирует в нее значение 1 из переменной a и метод будет работать именно с $a, по этому на оригинальной а это никак не отразится
Если у вас есть объект MyClass ref = new MyClass(), то при передачи в метод JVM создаст новый указатель $ref = ref. Если класс MyClass имеет mutable методы, то через них можно влиять на его состояние, если нет - то нет. Очевидно, что $ref = new MyClass() никак не повлияет на оригинальный ref

Исходя из вышесказанного, единственный вариант сделать так, как вы хотите - передать в качестве параметра mutable объект и изменять его поля, если мы говорим о методе другого класса. Если же метод этого же класса, то изменяйте поля напрямую.

Для методов, которые меняют внутреннее состояние объектов обязательно подбирайте говорящие об этом имена.

Answer (score 0):

Анонимный класс можно использовать.

Объявить интерфейс:

```
interface Incrementor{
        void inc();
        byte getValue();
}
```

Изменить `method` на что-то такое:

```
void method(Incrementor value, byte x){
     switch(value.getValue()){
        case 9: x--; value.inc(); break;
        case 10: x-=2; value.inc(); break;
        case 11: x-=3; value.inc(); break;
        case 12: x-=4; value.inc(); break;
        case 13: x-=5; value.inc(); break;
        case 14: x-=7; value.inc(); break;
        case 15: x-=9; vvalue.inc(); break;
      }
}
```

Вызывать так:

```
if(true)
    method(new Incrementor(){
          public void inc(){
              s.value1++;
          }

          public byte getValue(){
              return s.value1;
          }
    }, counter);
else
    method(new Incrementor(){
          public void inc(){
              s.value2++;
          }              
          public byte getValue(){
              return s.value2;
          }
    }, counter);
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то интерфейс может быть только у абстрактного класса?

Comment: @andrew интерфейс и абстрактный класс - две разные вещи.

Comment: switch(value) - тут ошибку выдает: "Cannot switch on a value of type Incrementor"

Comment: @andrew поправил ответ. Просто метод `getValue` можно добавить в интерфейс.